# Changing color of div when moving to another list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that consists of three different array Red Fruits, Green Fruits and `Suggested Fruits` I am able to splice and push a single array value from `Suggested Fruits` to `green and red fruits list` according to their array key but the problem is that i'm trying to make it so that whenever i move the values from random list to either `green/red fruits list` it will be a different colour not red or green. so for example when i move a value from `random fruits` to `red fruits list` it will be pink colour and when it comes back it will be the original colour grey and same for when i move `random fruits value to green fruits list`. I tired adding the `pink css` into the class but it doesn't seem to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var fruits = [{
    fruit: "Apple",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Tomato",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Lime",
    type: "2"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Guava",
    type: "2"
  },
];
var fruitTypeMap = {
  "1": "Red Fruits",
  "2": "Green Fruits"
}
var fruitTypes = {
  "Red Fruits": ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry'],
  "Green Fruits": ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'],
  "Random Fruits": fruits.map(fruit => fruit.fruit)
};
var clonePill = $(".clone");
Object.keys(fruitTypes).forEach(key => {
  fruitTypes[key].forEach(fruit => {
    var $newFruit = clonePill.clone();
    $newFruit.removeClass("clone");
    $newFruit.text(fruit);
    $(`[data-fruits="${key}"]`).append($newFruit);
  });
});

function moveFruit(e) {
  var fruitCategory = $(this).parent().data("fruits");
  var fruitName = $(this).text();
  var $fruit = $(this).detach();
  if (fruitCategory === "Random Fruits") {
    var fruitType = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.fruit === fruitName).type;
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitTypeMap[fruitType]];
    var fruitIndex = fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitArr.push(fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $fruit.addClass("movable pinkcolor");
    $(`[data-fruits="${fruitTypeMap[fruitType]}"]`).append($fruit);
  } else {
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitCategory];
    var fruitIndex = fruitArr.indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].push(fruitArr.splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $('[data-fruits="Random Fruits"]').append($fruit);
  }
}
$(".red-fruits, .green-fruits").on("click", ".movable", moveFruit);
$(".random-fruits").on("click", ".fruit-pill", moveFruit);

var lol = JSON.stringify(fruitTypes);
console.log(lol);
```

```css
.clone {
  display: none;
}

.fruit-pill {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.green-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.random-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skillpanel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.longpanel {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="skillpanel">
    <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox red-fruits" data-fruits="Red Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox green-fruits" data-fruits="Green Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="longpanel">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox random-fruits" data-fruits="Random Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fruit-pill clone"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bobby, you need to change

1) In css

```
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

to below

```
.pinkcolor {
  background-color: pink !important;
}
```

2) When you move back you need original gray color back so you need to add

```
$fruit.removeClass("movable pinkcolor");
```

with else condition of your moveFruit function.

Try with

```js
var fruits = [{
    fruit: "Apple",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Tomato",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Lime",
    type: "2"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Guava",
    type: "2"
  },
];
var fruitTypeMap = {
  "1": "Red Fruits",
  "2": "Green Fruits"
}
var fruitTypes = {
  "Red Fruits": ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry'],
  "Green Fruits": ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'],
  "Random Fruits": fruits.map(fruit => fruit.fruit)
};
var clonePill = $(".clone");
Object.keys(fruitTypes).forEach(key => {
  fruitTypes[key].forEach(fruit => {
    var $newFruit = clonePill.clone();
    $newFruit.removeClass("clone");
    $newFruit.text(fruit);
    $(`[data-fruits="${key}"]`).append($newFruit);
  });
});

function moveFruit(e) {
  var fruitCategory = $(this).parent().data("fruits");
  var fruitName = $(this).text();
  var $fruit = $(this).detach();
  if (fruitCategory === "Random Fruits") {
    var fruitType = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.fruit === fruitName).type;
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitTypeMap[fruitType]];
    var fruitIndex = fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitArr.push(fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $fruit.addClass("movable pinkcolor");
    $(`[data-fruits="${fruitTypeMap[fruitType]}"]`).append($fruit);
  } else {
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitCategory];
    var fruitIndex = fruitArr.indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].push(fruitArr.splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $fruit.removeClass("movable pinkcolor");
    $('[data-fruits="Random Fruits"]').append($fruit);
  }
}
$(".red-fruits, .green-fruits").on("click", ".movable", moveFruit);
$(".random-fruits").on("click", ".fruit-pill", moveFruit);

var lol = JSON.stringify(fruitTypes);
console.log(lol);
```

```css
  .clone {
  display: none;
}

.fruit-pill {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.green-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.random-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skillpanel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.longpanel {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
}

.pinkcolor {
  background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="skillpanel">
    <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox red-fruits" data-fruits="Red Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox green-fruits" data-fruits="Green Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="longpanel">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox random-fruits" data-fruits="Random Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fruit-pill clone"></div>
```

Comment: you wrote me fast :))))

Answer (score 0):

First add css code:

```
 .pinkcolor{ 
      background-color: pink !important;
    }
```

After change moveFruit function

```
function moveFruit(e) {
  var fruitCategory = $(this).parent().data("fruits");
  var fruitName = $(this).text();
  var $fruit = $(this).detach();
  if (fruitCategory === "Random Fruits") {
    var fruitType = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.fruit === fruitName).type;
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitTypeMap[fruitType]];
    var fruitIndex = fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitArr.push(fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $fruit.addClass("movable pinkcolor");
    $(`[data-fruits="${fruitTypeMap[fruitType]}"]`).append($fruit);
  } else {
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitCategory];
    var fruitIndex = fruitArr.indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].push(fruitArr.splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $('[data-fruits="Random Fruits"]').append($fruit);
    $fruit.removeClass("movable pinkcolor"); //add this
  }
}
```

> P.S: your css code class name is "pink". but js code addclass name is
>   pinkcolor.

hope is right :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using `!important` :

- define a new CSS class `original` that gives the red or green color to the `fruit-pills`.
- add this class to every fruit
- when moving a random fruit to the green or red fruits div, remove the `original` class.

```js
var fruits = [{
    fruit: "Apple",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Tomato",
    type: "1"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Lime",
    type: "2"
  },
  {
    fruit: "Guava",
    type: "2"
  },
];
var fruitTypeMap = {
  "1": "Red Fruits",
  "2": "Green Fruits"
}
var fruitTypes = {
  "Red Fruits": ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry'],
  "Green Fruits": ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'],
  "Random Fruits": fruits.map(fruit => fruit.fruit)
};
var clonePill = $(".clone");
Object.keys(fruitTypes).forEach(key => {
  fruitTypes[key].forEach(fruit => {
    var $newFruit = clonePill.clone();
    $newFruit.removeClass("clone");
    $newFruit.addClass("original");
    $newFruit.text(fruit);
    $(`[data-fruits="${key}"]`).append($newFruit);
  });
});

function moveFruit(e) {
  var fruitCategory = $(this).parent().data("fruits");
  var fruitName = $(this).text();
  var $fruit = $(this).detach();
  if (fruitCategory === "Random Fruits") {
    var fruitType = fruits.find(fruit => fruit.fruit === fruitName).type;
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitTypeMap[fruitType]];
    var fruitIndex = fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitArr.push(fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $fruit.addClass("movable pink");
    $fruit.removeClass("original");
    $(`[data-fruits="${fruitTypeMap[fruitType]}"]`).append($fruit);
  } else {
    var fruitArr = fruitTypes[fruitCategory];
    var fruitIndex = fruitArr.indexOf(fruitName);
    fruitTypes["Random Fruits"].push(fruitArr.splice(fruitIndex, 1)[0]);
    $('[data-fruits="Random Fruits"]').append($fruit);
  }
}
$(".red-fruits, .green-fruits").on("click", ".movable", moveFruit);
$(".random-fruits").on("click", ".fruit-pill", moveFruit);

var lol = JSON.stringify(fruitTypes);
console.log(lol);
```

```css
.clone {
  display: none;
}

.fruit-pill {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-fruits>.original {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.green-fruits>.original {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

.random-fruits>.fruit-pill {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skillpanel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.longpanel {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="skillpanel">
    <div style="float:left;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox red-fruits" data-fruits="Red Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:calc(50% - 5px);">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox green-fruits" data-fruits="Green Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="longpanel">
      <div class="wrappingflexbox random-fruits" data-fruits="Random Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fruit-pill clone"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, your `pinkcolor` class on CSS is not `pinkcolor` class  but `pink` class.

Second, you can try adding `!important` value to your `background-color: pink`

**CSS CODE**

```
    .pinkcolor{ /*I change your class, from pink to pinkcolor here */
      background-color: pink !important; //Adding !important
    }
```